# Can I convert a sequence of wxi files to a Visual Studio Wix Project?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a lot of wxi files for a Wix setup.
All together works great as a setup but I think But it works good.
But with changes and extensions it is extremely confusing.

Looks like:

```
Product.wxs
App.wxi
CustomAction.wxi
Firewall.wxi
Feature.wxi
en-us.wxl
```

Can I convert all these somehow to a Visual Studio Wix Project? And if yes how I can do it?

Comment: WiX has the flexibility needed to make pretty much anything you need, [Visual Studio Installer Projects have many limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130) ([short list form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637666/129130)). I would not recommend going for a conversion - especially since this setup looks to be complicated enough to require WiX's flexibility.

Comment: If you go [here](http://www.installdude.com) and click the *"WiX Samples"* entry there is a list of WiX resources in the grid. Also, have a look at ["WiX Quick Start" section here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130).

Comment: Added one more link below, [alternative MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840) - along with some comments to make the answer more "generic" (for others with similar questions).

Answer (score 0):

***Short Version***: Below is an attempted generic answer: **`1)`** You can use another tool such as Advanced Installer or Installshield, **`2)`** you can find help with WiX to continue to use it, and **`3)`** you can even use **`dark.exe`** to convert other MSIs to WiX format (this can help you with WiX markup syntax - you can implement in another tool and covert to WiX - then the markup will work).

---

WiX is particularly good - I think - for corporate in-house use (large companies) where expertise is readily available and can be maintained over time. For a lone developer who does setups once a year it might be too much to handle with all the flexibility and syntax?

---

***Alternative Tools***: [I forget my ad-hoc quick overview of MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840) in the comments above. Both [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com) ([help portal](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29130)) and [Installshield](https://www.revenera.com/install/products/installshield.html) have excellent features that makes you able to deliver setups quicker than with WiX.

Advanced Installer and Installshield should have features to import many project types. I have not tested lately, there could be changes.

***Update***: **https://www.advancedinstaller.com/import.html**

---

***VS Installer Projects Limitations***: WiX has the flexibility needed to make pretty much anything you need, [Visual Studio Installer Projects have many limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130) ([short list form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637666/129130)). I would not recommend going for a conversion - especially since this setup looks to be complicated enough to require WiX's flexibility.

***WiX Quick Start Material***: If you go [here](http://www.installdude.com/) and click the "WiX Samples" entry there is a list of WiX resources in the grid. [Also, have a look at "WiX Quick Start" section here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130).

[***Dark.exe***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1188124/129130): In fact, WiX has a tool called **`Dark.exe`** which can be used to decompile an MSI file to WiX markup. In other words it is generally easier to move to WiX than from it - although Advanced Installer and Installshield should be able to import WiX and other project files and also import MSI files.

***Dark.exe, Sample Syntax***:

```
dark.exe -x outputfolder MySetup.msi
```

An answer on MSI files and viewers: [How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546)